# Why the picture doesn't draw on iPad2?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

the following code works like a charm in Chrome, Safari and Firefox
but doesn't work in my iPad2 iOS5
why

```
function preImage(url,callback){
  var img = new Image(); 
  img.src = url;

  if (img.complete) { 
    callback.call(img);
    return; 
  }

  img.onload = function (){ 
     callback.call(img);
  };
}
(function() {
  var my_canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context=my_canvas.getContext("2d");
  preImage("img/test.png",function(){
    context.drawImage(this,0,0);
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appears to work fine on my iPhone, and iPad simulator, both running IOS6. I notice you said IOS5, typo? or intended?

```
var preImage = function(url, callback){
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = url;

    if (img.complete) { 
        callback.call(img);
        return; 
    }

    img.onload = function (){ 
        callback.call(img);
    };
};
(function() {
    var my_canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = my_canvas.getContext("2d");
    preImage("img/picture.jpg", function(){
        context.drawImage(this,0,0);
    });
})();
```

Notice the addition of the ';' after the preImage declaration.